# Why QGIS Zonal Statistics gives me wrong results?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, zonal-statistics

I'm learning QGIS and tried zonal statistics, but for some reason it gives me wrong results and I don't know why.

This red pixel contains value 1.

[image]

Then I create a polygon on top of it.

[image]

And then Zonal statistics, which gives me wrong sum and count.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That means there are 16 pixels (4x4) in the red layer. Because `_count=16`, `_sum=16`, `_mean=1`. If this is true, you will get `_count=16`, `_sum=32`, `_mean=2` if you change raster values to `2`.

Comment: I tested this with another raster pixel with value 2 and looks like you are right. 

Is there any way to extract/calculate raster band values with zonal statistics tool or..? I created the raster layer from vector grid layer. 

My goal is just to create areas/buffers and calculate values within the area they cover.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To your question in the comment, yes, you can choose the band of the raster in the Zonal stats tool (gives you an option to choose the band). I think you might need to run the command several times for different bands, but it is possible:

[image]

Also, you mention creating buffers - you can do that with a specific command from the geoprocessing toolkit around the points: Vector Geometry => Buffer:

[image]